# create ipa xcode 7 error: jquery-mobile and external call

Tags: xcode, jquery-mobile, web-applications, xcode7, ipa

I have a strange problem with the creation of **ipa**.
I have a web-app with an old ipa.
Now, I have the latest version of **Xcode (7)**, I've tried to do a new ipa with the same  files (of that web-app) and it doesn't work.
When I create the new ipa, I select *"create for ad hoc deployment"* and I don't send it immediately to app store.
I noticed that the new ipa is smaller than the old ipa.
I can install the web-app on my iphone and the app starts, but the jquery-mobile seems doesn't work.
Also, it seems that it can't do external calls (for example to a website).
If I install the old ipa, it works all.
I program the web-app with phonegap not with xcode.
I use xcode only to create the ipa.
Anyone know if there are problems with new version of Xcode?
I've tried the new ipa with iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus.
With apk for android works perfectly.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.
The external links were the problem.
In the new Xcode it's necessary to add a code in the config.xml that contain the external links that the web-app uses.